# Application that can load both C/C++ and Python plugins

Tags: c++, python, c, plugins, shared-libraries

I want to create an application that is capable of loading plugins. The twist is that I want to be able to create plugins in both C/C++ and Python.

So I've started thinking about this and have a few questions that I'm hoping people can help me with.

My first question is whether I need to use C/C++ for the "core" of the application (the part that actually does the loading of the plugins)? This is my feeling at least, I would think that implementing the core in Python would result in a nasty performance hit, but it would probably simplify loading the plugins dynamically.

Second question is how would I go about defining the plugin interface for C/C++ on one hand and Python on the other? The plugin interface would be rather simple, just a single method that accepts a list of image as a parameter and returns a list of images as a return value. I will probably use the OpenCV image type within the plugins which exists for both C/C++ and Python.

Finally, I would like the application to dynamically discover plugins. So if you place either a .py file or a shared library file (.so/.dll) in this directory, the application would be able to produce a list of available plugins at runtime.

I found something in the Boost library called Boost.Extension (http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/index.html) but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a part of the official Boost library and it also seems to be a bit stale now. On top of that, I don't know how well it would work with Python, that is, how easy it would be to create Python plugins that fit into this mechanism.

As a side note, I imagine the application split into two "parts". One part is a stripped down core (loading and invoking plugin instances from a "recipe"). The other part is the core plus a GUI that I plan on writing in Python (using PySide). This GUI will enable the user to define the aforementioned "recipes". This GUI part would require the core to be able to provide a list of available plugins.

Sorry for the long winded "question". I guess I'm hoping for more of a discussion and of course if anybody knows of something similar that would help me I would very much appreciate a pointer. I would also appreciate any concise and to the point reading material about something similar (such as integrating C/C++ and Python etc).

Comment: Take a look at LibSoup if you are using GObject.

Comment: Why don't you write your C/C++ code as a standard Python extension, either directly or through SWIG, Boost, Cython, or several other methods? Then do what snøreven suggests and just import the files from the plugin directory, then call it with some extension initialization hook.

Answer (score 1):

Write your application in Python, then you can have a folder for your plugins.

Your application searches for them by checking the directory/traversing the plugin tree.

Then import them via "import" or use ctypes for a .so/.dll, or even easier: you can use boost::python for creating a .so/.dll that you can 'import' like a normal python module.

Don't use C++ and try to do scripting in Python - that really sucks, you will regret it. ;)

Comment: That's definitely easier to implement... but I'm rather worried about performance. The idea is to have the plugins process images in a video stream so performance is of rather high importance. If I write the core in python, it means that plugin instances would have to be invoked by the python interpreter which is probably going to hurt performance pretty bad.

Comment: Have you thought about cython, like Andrew Dalke suggested? Invokation itself is done only once, so that's not the problem. Python plugins could be, for image processing... I don't know what you are writing, but chances are that most of your application is not time critical - you always can write parts of it in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The application is a image processing pipeline of sorts. So for a video stream for example, each frame will pass through plugins in a "pipeline fashion" so there is really no way around having multiple invocations for the plugins without sacrificing the dynamic nature of the program (being able to define and change the pipeline in between runs).

So unfortunately most of my application runtime is time critical.

I think it's a good idea though to use the Boost:Python but figure out some way to write the plugin invocation part in C.

Thanks again for very good pointers.

Comment: I would check out cython then. That way you can compile everything to C.